# Java 8 filter a stream to replace SQL IN (...) clause

Tags: java

Is there any way to achieve the same result with a collection like with SQL IN clause ? For example, there a list of objects and I have to choose those with ids in (2, 17, 31, ...) what is equal to SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...);
```

Comment: You know about the [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method, right?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. `collection.stream().filter(e -> validValues.contains(e.getName()))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a predicate in the filter to emulate the `IN` clause:

A litle and non tested example:

```
List<Number> myList= Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> finalList= Arrays
    .stream(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })
    .filter(element -> myList.contains(element))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The output should be `1, 2, 3`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do that:

```
private static void selectByRange(List<Integer> range) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 20, 23, 101);
        Stream<Integer> filterStream = numbers.stream().filter((Integer number) -> range.contains(number));
        List<Integer> collected = filterStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(collected.toString());

    }
```

You pass in a list of Integers and get the filtered list:

```
selectByRange(Arrays.asList(5, 3, 4, 20, 100)); #=> [3, 4, 5, 20]
```

Comment: Note that you can replace `(Integer number) -> range.contains(number)` with the much more readable `range::contains`.

Comment: @biziclop, yep, good catch, thnx. Not sure about readability :)

Comment: And you'd better use a Set<Integer> rather than a List: List.contains is O(N), whereas Set.contains is O(1).

Answer (score -2):

Just use Apache Commons Collection

```
ListUtils.intersection(numbers, range);
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#intersection